# Does NSBundle cache on start all it's contents some how?

Tags: foundation, nsbundle

I had a problem with retrieving files that I wrote to bundle just before accessing it. (Actually I couldn't access it during all app launch). But after restart, same method found the file I wrote during first app launch.

So finally I found a solution, but I'm not sure if I truly understand how bundle works

(my file was `menu.xml` and I wrote it in root directory of bundle (to resourcePath))

At first I used instance method [`- pathForResource:ofType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) 
didn't work on first launch. But found on second.

Than I tried [`+ pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:). It worked both times.

So the Question is: 
Does NSBundle cache something? Or why instance method didn't work at first time, before relaunching? If you have some ideas for investigation, I would be glad to hear them.